# Adding environment variable to a commandline argument in a windows shortcut

Tags: windows, email, environment-variables, shortcut

So I'm trying to make a mailto link on a windows desktop. This is to automate opening a mail client by inserting the recipient and subject automatically. I can do just that, however I'd like to include either the current date or the previous date in the beginning of the subject line. I've tried:

%windir%\explorer.exe mailto://user@email.com?subject=%date% 'Rest Of Subject'

and every other variant I can think of. The link either reads %windir% correctly or just skips it but opens fine. However, I see the literal '%date' in my subject.

Is this possible without using batch files or scripting? This is for work different computers at different locations, where users aren't exactly computer savvy and need things done for them. Also for bonus points, is there a way the also make the file attach dialog pop up? The purpose of this is to send security log word document from different locations to a central email address. Thanks and I hope to hear from anyone who can direct me where to look or give me some hints on my command line fu!

Comment: `%date%` is a cmd.exe function, not a real environment variable.  Perhaps try something like `cmd /c start mailto://...`